# I want to take a bus from Dusseldorf Airport to NH Hotel City Centre - please tell me what would be the bus number

Tags: airport-transfer, dusseldorf, dus

How to reach NH Dusseldorf City Centre Hotel from Dusseldorf Airport?

Comment: What time are you arriving at the airport? From Google Maps, it seems the easiest way is to take the 707 tram (includes about a 20-minute walk). There doesn't seem to be a direct bus.

Answer (score 2):

You first take the train to Düsseldorf Hbf (main station). It is a 5 to 10 minutes ride (depending on the number of stops) and there are some 6 to 8 trains/hour.

From there, you can either walk about 10 minutes to your hotel or take the 709 or 719 tram to the "Berliner Allee" stop and walk from there.

Taking a taxi from the airport to the hotel is of course also an option and will cost you about 20€.

I don't know why Google Maps suggests to take the 707 tram all the way. That sounds like one of the least attractive options.

Comment: Google Maps doesn't always seem to know about German trains, so can often suggest odd routings by public transport using only ones it does know about